# The right place for "...of which"

Tags: relative-clauses

Where should we put the relative clause?

"So how do you know which sites to use or which information to trust? Much of it is misleading."

- So how do you know which sites to use or which information, much of which is misleading, to trust?
- So how do you know which sites to use or which information to trust, much of which is misleading?

Comment: Both versions are grammatically correct. The second one is much more natural.

Comment: @gotube - Surely not? _Much of which_  must refer to _information_ and not _sites_, so the first is correct (though using _which_ three times is infelicitous).

Comment: @KateBunting Agreed, using commas for parentheses defines exactly what is misleading. If you mean both the sites and the information then you could say **,both of which are  mostly misleading,**. I also agree about using the same word more than once in a sentence.

Comment: @KateBunting My brain consistently parses the second one with "*much of which is misleading*" as referring to "*information*", which is the closest noun to it.